# change background with Css

Tags: html, css, django

I want to change my background site so at first it changed but when I trying to change it again to another color it not happen I link my code file with style.css file with this code

`{% load static %}`

style.css (code):in my style.css folder

```
body{
background-color: blue;}
```

first I changed the background  to brown then I want to change it to blue but it doesn't change

(also when I go to my site it still brown also when I use this code in style.css (body{
background-color: blue} when I click on inspect it appears to me body{
background-color: brown} )

Comment: refresh the webpage using ctrl + F5 and check again

Comment: sharing only the piece of code makes it hard to know your problem.

Comment: Refresh the page, restart the server and clear the caches of your browser.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development

Comment: Have you linked css in your templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a technical problem with Django as that CSS code would normally work for me in VS Code.

Try writing that CSS code in the HTML file in a Style tag, although I'm not sure if that'll work for files committed into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the CSS file if ctrl f5 does not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to add templates in your `setting.py` as well as `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
   then you have to restart your server with this command.
2. You have to add CSS file in your static folder and that folder in your project
   then it will work.

See more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files